# Not able to mock Laravel Model method

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

I am currently writing a test to test a model method.

My model `Store` has this method:

```
public function hourTemplate() {
    return $this->belongsTo(HourTemplate::class);
}
```

I have a test as well with this code in setUp method:

```
public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->storeMock = Mockery::mock(StoreModel::class)->makePartial();
        app()->instance(StoreModel::class, $this->storeMock);
    }
```

And test method is like this:

```
    public function test_getStoreHoursArray_when_hour_isNull() {
        $this->storeMock->shouldReceive('hourTemplate')->andReturn(new HourTemplate());

        dump((new StoreModel())->hourTemplate);

    }
```

But the returned value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the mocked instance from the container

```
$mockedModel = app()->make(StoreModel::class);
```